# why can't I declare a variable, convert it to an integer and use that integer in my code?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to create a playlist of audio files. The html contains three audio tags:

```
<ul id="myAudio">
    <li>
        <audio class="audio" id="1" controls>
            <source src="_audio/Clear_Vision.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
    </li>
    <li>
        <audio class="audio" id="2" controls>
            <source src="_audio/Greensleeves.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
    </li>
    <li>
        <audio class="audio" id="3" controls>
            <source src="_audio/Pavane21Sec.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so far my javascript(jquery) is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

    var x = 1;
    x = parseInt(x);


    var deisredAudio = $('source:nth(0)').attr('src');

    audioElement.setAttribute('src', deisredAudio);

    $.get();

    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function(){
        audioElement.play();
    }, true);

    $('#playAudio').click(function(){
        audioElement.play();
    });

    $('#pauseAudio').click(function(){
        audioElement.pause();
    });
});
```

This will play the audio track as long as I have an integer in the `$('source:nth(0)')`.

This will play the first audio, `$('source:nth(1)')` will play the second and so on as expected.

What I need to do is insert a variable to eventually create a loop to loop through and play the audio tracks.

When I declare a variable `x = 1`, and then insert it into `$('source:nth(x)')`, it does not work.

Please note that I am self-taught in JavaScript.

Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take it out of quotes and pass it into your `:nth()` using string concatenation:

```
$('source:nth(' + x + ')')
```

...otherwise you're using the character literal "x".

Comment: Thanks a lot James. I would have never figured it out myself.